# How the variance of a potential loss X has been derived

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, variance

I'm studying Insurance and I have a question about how the variance has been computed in this example.

Imagine a case where an "agent" may suffer a loss, because of an event (an accident) occurring within a stated period.

$\varepsilon$ is the event which causes the financial loss whereas $\bar{\varepsilon}$ represents the absence of the accident. $x$ is the amount of the loss itself. We are assuming that, if the event occurs, the amount of the loss is certain. 
We can formally represent the potential loss with the random number  $X$, defined as follow:

$$X = \begin{cases} x, & \mbox{if } \varepsilon \\ 0, & \mbox{if } \bar{\varepsilon} \end{cases}$$

The probability of the event $\varepsilon$ is:
$$p=P[\varepsilon]$$
Knowing that, I can compute the expected value of the potential loss of $X$, hence:
$$E[X]=x \cdot p$$

Now my doubt: the variance (stated by the book) is given by
$$Var[X]=x^2\cdot p(1-p)$$

---

I tried to understand how the formula has been computed. First of all, I know that the variance is given by
$$Var[X]=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~=E(x^2)-[E(X)]^2$$
$$~~=x^2-x^2\cdot p^2$$
$$~~~=x^2\cdot (1-p^2)$$

which is different from the formula that has been stated by the book.
Could please give me some hint on how to derive correctly $Var[X]$ for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the second moment (which is wrong in your case), $$E[X^2]=(x^2)p+(0^2)(1-p)=x^2p$$ Then use $$\operatorname{var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=x^2p-(xp)^2=x^2(p-p^2)=x^2p(1-p)$$